# Change in SQL generated by ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a model called User with this table definition:

```
create :users do
  t.string :email
  t.integer :status # 0 for OPEN, 1 for CLOSED
end
```

and the following query:

```
User.where(status: ["OPEN"])
```

On Rails 5.2 with Ruby 2.2 the query would generate this SQL:

```
select * from users where status = 0
```

After upgrading to Rails 6 and Ruby 2.5.5 and adding frozen_string_literal: true, the SQL it generates is:

```
select * from users where status = NULL
```

Why this change in behavior?

Comment: Where are you adding the `frozen_string_literal`?

Comment: Sebs, it's in the controller. But it doesn't have anything to do. When running the AR queries in the console it happens the same.

Comment: Are you using `enum` with the status column in the model? I have the last result you added if I remove the enum method in the model, otherwise it work as in your first example.

Comment: No, it's an integer.

Comment: So the same thing happens in the console as well?

If so: please remove the parts of the question that relate to controller/action stuff and 
show the model code instead.

Comment: Why are you even doing this in the first place? If you're using ActiveRecord::Enum you should just be able to use `User.open` or `User.where(status: :open)`. I can't understand why you would want to use an array which is used to create `WHERE a IN bs` queries.

Comment: Legacy app getting a revamp. I'd like to understand what went on there